# How to change solr.jetty.request.header.size in docker

Tags: solr, sitecore

I have created a Solr version 8.1.1 in Azure using a Docker for Sitecore. I get the following error for a large query

ERROR Error during executing a query.

```
Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException
Message: <h1>Bad Message 431</h1><pre>reason: Request Header Fields Too Large</pre>
Source: SolrNet
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrQueryExecuter`1.Execute(ISolrQuery q, QueryOptions options)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.LinqToSolrIndex`1.ExecuteQuery(SolrCompositeQuery compositeQuery, QueryOptions options)
Nested Exception
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (431) Request Header Fields Too Large.
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
```

Comment: Using a POST request instead of a GET request doesn't work? Solr supports all queries as POST requests instead. If that doesn't change anything - why is the sent headers so large?

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh We are using Post Request. the same code works file when we use Azure search. Even Solr search works for simple quires

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve the issue by redeploy the Docker instance by updating the YML file with the following setting under environment section.

```
- SOLR_OPTS=-Dsolr.jetty.request.header.size=65535
```

Comment: It's important to note that this setting also solves the error "414 - URI Too Long".